# Free voxel editor?

Tags: tools, models, editors, voxels

Does anyone know of a good free voxel editor and/or voxel-to-mesh converter?

Comment: Does "Minecraft creative mode" count?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thermite3D is a voxel-based game engine.  It isn't an editor per se.  It does, however, have a list of voxel editors on its wiki here: [Thermite-Recommended Voxel Editors](https://bitbucket.org/volumesoffun/polyvox/wiki/Voxel%20editors).

Of those, Sproxel, Voxel, and QBlock are all free.  Paint3d and Everygraph (Voxel3d) have trial versions, and one not on the list, [Qubicle Constructor](http://www.minddesk.com/), has a crippled trial as well.

Comment: Note that the Thermite-Recommended Voxel Editors wiki page has moved to https://bitbucket.org/volumesoffun/polyvox/wiki/Voxel%20editors

Answer (score 5):

I wrote one for my Voxel Roguelike. You can get it here: [link](http://bigbadwofl.blogspot.com/2012/02/voxel-editor.html)

If you need some info on the file format, just post a question on the blog and I can help you out.

Comment: That looks amazing!

Answer (score 4):

There's also [Thermite3D](http://www.thermite3d.org/joomla/).  I've looked at it a little but haven't actually used it.  The forum community is very friendly and helpful, however.

Comment: PolyVox (previously part of Thermite3D) can now be found at [a new site](http://www.volumesoffun.com/polyvox-about/).

Answer (score 4):

You can try this (highly experimental)

http://popelka.misto.cz/cubes/cubes.htm

Answer (score 2):

You could try this one http://dmytry.pandromeda.com/voxelworld/, though I think it's not being maintained anymore (still, it's open-source, should you want to mess with the code).

Answer (score 0):

This is the one I use, by Eric Haines: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~min/binvox/